# The confidence level alfa value for spatial randomness with Ripley K and L function

Tags: r, spatstat

I have a point set of the spatial distribution of twitter posts relevant to a certain event.
[image]

I would like to evaluate evidence for clustering or dispersion of points. This is usually performed by comparing the distributions of the observed values of Ripley K and L inhomogeneous functions to the theoretical values of a Poisson point process in which the events are distributed independently according to a uniform probability distribution over the region.

I did all computations in R using Kinhom Linhom functions and I compared the distribution with respect to the Poisson distribution I would also like to add the confidential interval (I applied `plot(envelope(...)` with 99 simulations) the problem that I am having is that I can not understand how much is the alpha value?

[image]

The help section of the R says  `alpha = 2 * nrank/(1 + nsim)` - but how much is the `nrank`, or how I can compute it(obtain it)?

Total number of the observations of the pointdataset is 154.

Comment: As the documentation states, `nrank` defaults to 1, meaning the highest and lowest simulated values are used for the critical envelope. If the observed values lie below or above this then then the null hypothesis can be rejected. Thus, if you  want alpha = 0.01 with `nrank` at default, set `nsim` to 199. What this entails is explained quite expansively in the documentation (`?spatstat::envelope`).

Comment: What are you using as an observation window? Because if its the rectangle enclosing the plot I'd say there was overwhelming evidence of clustering simply from the observation that there's nothing in the lower right of it.

Comment: I used the rectangle as the observation window, and I agree that there was overwhelming evidence of clustering. For that reason, I used Ripley K and L inhomogeneous functions. 
@Spacedman do you have any suggestions for the observation window?

Comment: The observation window is the region where data would have been observed had there been data generated. So for example if this data is all the data within a country boundary, you use the country boundary.